# Difference between a void result and a specific result

Tags: java, linked-list, insert, void

i got a little problem. The following code inserts a given element in a sorted LinkedList. If i run this method as a void-method, the result is wrong. For example the list before is 1,2,3. If i start the method with 2 as insert, it works correctly. but if i insert a number smaller 1 or bigger 3, it doesn't work.

if i change the method to give back the head of the new linked list, it works perfectly.

whats wrong here?

Here you can see both codes:

```
static void insertIter (simplyLinkedList head, int insert, Comparator cmp){

    if (head == null) return;

    simplyLinkedList last = null;
    simplyLinkedList actual = head;
    simplyLinkedList add = new simplyLinkedList(insert);

    while (actual != null){

        if (cmp.compareInt(insert, actual.key) == -1 || cmp.compareInt(insert, actual.key ) == 0){

            add.next = actual;

            if (last == null){

                head = add;

            }
            else {

                last.next = add;

            }
            return;
        }   
        last = actual;
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    if (actual == null){

        last.next = add;
        add.next = null;    
    }

    return;
}




static simplyLinkedList insertIter (simplyLinkedList head, int insert, Comparator cmp){

    if (head == null) return null;

    simplyLinkedList last = null;
    simplyLinkedList actual = head;
    simplyLinkedList add = new simplyLinkedList(insert);

    while (actual != null){

        if (cmp.compareInt(insert, actual.key) == -1 || cmp.compareInt(insert, actual.key ) == 0){

            add.next = actual;

            if (last == null){

                head = add;

            }
            else {

                last.next = add;

            }
            return head;
        }   
        last = actual;
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    if (actual == null){

        last.next = add;
        add.next = null;    
    }

    return head;
}
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: You didn't show how these methods are used, but it seems you are passing a reference to the head of the list to both of these methods. The methods change this local variable, which has no effect on the caller. Therefore, only if you return the local variable, the caller will have the new head of the list.

Comment: @Eran In the main i initialized the linked list  (1,2,3) and then i make this calls: insertIter(head,0,cmp); print(head). the method print gets a head of a linked List an gives it out on the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you change the value of `head`:

```
if (last == null){
    head = add;
}
```

That changes the **argument**'s value. It has no effect on the calling code's version of that. So for instance, if the calling code was

```
insertIter(foo, 1, someComparator);
```

...changing `head` in `insertIter` has no effect whatsoever on the value of `foo`; `foo` still contains the old value.

Since you might have to change `head`, you'll need to return it (as you've discovered), and do this:

```
foo = insertIter(foo, 1, someComparator);
```

Remember that variables contain values, and it's the value, not the variable, that is passed into a method. The value related to an object is called an object reference. It's akin to a number that the JVM uses to locate the object in memory. `foo` above might contain `Ref55465` (we never see these actual values), and even if you change the value in `head` from `Ref55465` to `Ref66548`, `foo` still contains `Ref55465`.

Comment: thanks for your help! i'd like to test the void method in my main. How can I do that? in the main i initialized my linked-list and then i called the void-method with the head of my linked list. i thought, that after this call in the main, my head ist changed there! i don't know what to do, because the task-position is, to write a void method, not a method with a specified return ...

Comment: @KSV97: I'd suggest you do what the JDK does: Make `simplyLinkedList` the list, rather than the head of the list, and make `head` a field within it. Then you can pass the list reference around, knowing that that value (the reference to the list object) doesn't change, just the object's `head` field.